# php using name space library not found

Tags: php, composer-php

Follow the instruction to use composer to install [dukpt-php](https://github.com/camcima/dukpt-php), write a simple code:

```
<?php

use DUKPT\DerivedKey;
use DUKPT\KeySerialNumber;
use DUKPT\Utility;

$ksnObj = new KeySerialNumber($ksn);
$decryptionKey = DerivedKey::calculateDataEncryptionRequestKey($ksnObj, $bdk);
```

But get error:

```
Class 'DUKPT\KeySerialNumber' not found
```

Comment: have you included composer's autoloader?

Comment: I did not put in the autoloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include composer's autoloader:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some inconsistencies (really!?!) in PHP with this type of statement where you may need to use a rooted namespace 'use' statement:

```
use \DUKPT\Utility.
```